# build gcc failure(loongarch64): unrecognized option -'lp64d

Tags: gcc, build

*I was facing a problem that i have to compile GCC 12 in a new platform - loongarch64, here is one of the problem that i have facing in building, and i have checking all current threads*

### Environment

- Operating System: loongnix(linux)
- Architecture: loongarch64
- GCC(current): gcc (GCC) 8.3.0 20190222 (Loongson 8.3.0-35 vec)
- yum package(current): https://fars.ee/A66G

### recoding

1. clone the git repo
   https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc
   commit: 0d94c6df183375caaa7f672e288a2094ca813749
2. `mkdir build && cd build`
3. makeup a kind of configuration script

> the basic idea is disable all things to make it compile, but seem the performance no good, which still not compileable.

```bash
../configure -v \
    --build=loongarch64-linux-gnu   \
    --host=loongarch64-linux-gnu    \
    --target=loongarch64-linux-gnu  \
    --enable-languages=c,c++    \
    --disable-option-checking   \
    --disable-bootstrap
```

**output**: https://fars.ee/M9ki

```bash
../configure -v \
    --build=loongarch64-linux-gnu   \
    --host=loongarch64-linux-gnu    \
    --target=loongarch64-linux-gnu  \
    --enable-languages=c,c++    \
    --disable-option-checking   \
    --disable-shared        \
    --disable-threads       \
    --disable-libatomic     \
    --disable-libgomp       \
    --disable-libquadmath       \
    --disable-libssp        \
    --disable-libvtv        \
    --disable-libstdcxx     \
    --disable-bootstrap
```

**output**: https://fars.ee/dv1_

> It is important to note that it shows a kind of message like
> *** This configuration is not supported in the following subdirectories:
> target-libquadmath target-libstdc++-v3 target-libphobos gnattools gotools target-libada target-zlib target-libbacktrace target-libgfortran target-libgo target-libffi target-libgm2 target-libobjc target-libgomp target-libatomic target-libvtv target-libssp target-libitm target-libsanitizer
> (Any other directories should still work fine.)
> 4. `make -j 16 > out 2>&1`
> a: may facing a situation that we should clean our config.cache, BC the value has been change

**`output of version1`**: https://fars.ee/uL_A

**`build/config.log`**: https://fars.ee/keV5

**`build/loongarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc/config.log`**: https://fars.ee/vd5w

### some trying on debug:

1. I have trying to add some glibc yum packages.
2. Seem there is a CFLAGS `lp64d` adding it as Environment Variable Maybe help, but once I have added it into environment variables, configure could not work normally. I was guessing if the situation is due to my GCC compiler wasn't support `lp64d` compile flag.
3. there is a kind of error like `$CC -V or $CC -qversion commend-not-found`, but I have checked this command seems to haven't been support in even GCC12, thus i have no ideas how to solve these problems, just using `sed` or others to change this command? Finally, I have found a blog which say this error wasn't the real question that I'm facing, I should look forward.

I have tried a search on Google, but I really don't know what I need to search for, the major. Can anyone help me to solve this? Please bear in mind that I am new to this and so would appreciate being told in plain English what I need to do or where I need to start.